# How can i load javascript templates with their ids?

Tags: javascript, icanhaz.js

Been playing around some with iCanHaz.js templates which i define in the head of my html pages like this.

```
<script id="test" type="text/html">
<h1>Test</h1>
</script>
```

I do want to have all my iCanHaz templates in a single file and i dont know how i should import them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: depends on the server side environment

Comment: Using node.js for the server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They provide an example for how to pull templates from a server on [their site](http://icanhazjs.com/), almost at the bottom, if you use jQuery as well:

```
$.getJSON('/myserver/templates.json', function (templates) {
    $.each(templates, function (template) {
        ich.addTemplate(template.name, template.template);
    });
});
```

Then of course you would have to have some server-side code that provide the templates as JSON, and how you do that depends on what server-side language you are using, as pointed out by Poelinca Dorin in his comment.

Comment: oh, how could i miss that! Thanks.

Comment: this example is wrong $.each takes to arguments to callback function (id, elementAtId)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?  (it worked for jsRender templates):

```
<!--#include virtual="Scripts/RenderTemplates.js" -->
```